# Set Socket time out in SSL Connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, android-volley

Hi would like to know if there is a way to set a timeout to a socket and the numbers of retries that it does until the connection gets a handshake. I tested my app in very bad connection mode and i set a retry policy for my request in Volley to 10 sec but the SSL handshake seems to be the problem because it´s having a default timeout set by 60 sec and the Volley timeout only gets fired when the sockets fails becuase of the number of attempts or by the timeout .

Here is my method:

```
private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.muip);
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }

            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(trusted);



            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new NoSSLv3Factory(context.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sf);





            return sf;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "newSslSocketFactory: "+ e.getMessage(),e );
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
```

I am using Volley to make my requests and the method where i implementing this is in:

```
 public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack(null, newSslSocketFactory()));

            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
```

I also tried to set the timeout like this:

```
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new NoSSLv3Factory(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault(10000, new SSLSessionCache(this)));
```

Answer (score -1):

After `mRequestQueue.start()` you can set timeout this way:

```
int socketTimeout = 30000;   // 30 seconds - change to what you want
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Just read the questuon and descruption and u will know that the volley timeout depends on socket timeout

Comment: Please read the description well. I said it´s not on side of volley it its on SSL  Connection side when he tries to make the handshake. if even read the description well u will notice i am mentioning that i am already using a retry policy set to 10 seconds but it only gets fired when the sockets handshake fails